# Отправка формы

Tags: php, form

Есть форма, отправляется через POST. Заполняем ее неверными значениями, данные не проходят валидацию, результат отображается пользователю. Затем заполняем ее верными значениями и отправляем, ответом будет файл. Сохраняем его, страница после скачивания не обновляется. Если затем принудительно обновить страницу, то браузер предложит повторную отправку формы, соглашаемся - в POST будут данные от прошлого запроса, заполненные значениями, не прошедшими валидацию. Как обойти?

Comment: Как вы принудительно обновляете страницу?

Comment: Сбрасывайте пост данные редиректом.

> header("Location: " . "http://" .
> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $location)

Comment: @erbolking, а такой заголовок не помешает скачиванию файла?

Comment: Пробовал, мешает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте чистить поля с помощью JavaScript’а сразу после отправки формы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить в свою проверку добавить в свою проверку

```
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($info);
        $em->flush();
        --> return $this->redirectToRoute('contact'); <--(на эту же страницу)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Делайте перенаправление в самом конце: `header("Location: Ваш URL");`

2) Если можно использовать Javascript, то AJAX будет как раз.